# Hash key multiplying by 9 and modulus

Tags: c#, math, hash

I have this peculiar piece of code that is bothering me,

```
   // exbPtr points to 128-bit unsigned integer
   // lgID is a "short" with 0xFFFF being the max value

   int hash = (*exbPtr + (int)lgID * 9) & tlpLengthMask;
```

Initially this "hash table", which is really an array is initialized to 256 elements, and tlpLengthMask is set to 255.

Then there is this mysterious code .. with a comment right above it saying "if we reached here .. there has been a collision". And then it starts looping back again, so looks like this is a hash collision, and re-hashing?

```
   hash = (hash + (int)lgID * 2 + 1) & tlpLengthMask;
```

In addition, there is a ton of debug code that says that the length of this array should be a power of 2 because we're using mask as a modulus.

Can someone explain what the authors intent was? What is the reasoning behind this?

**EDIT** -- what I'm trying to discern is why he multiplied by 9, and then why multiply by 2 to re-hash.

Comment: Uh. What I don't understand is that he's multiplying by a non-prime number (9). Which is terrible in a hash calculation.

Comment: I'm pretty clueless when it comes to hashing .. why would he have chosen say 7? Or 11? Rather, what is "base reason" for multiplying with ANY number?

Comment: The reason is to distribute the output bits more evenly. For example, if he multiplies by 137, the sequence 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (decimal) goes from 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 binary to 0000 1001 0010 1011 0100. Which looks more even?

Comment: I don't think he needs a prime number here, all he needs is an odd number, so that the GCD is 1... Not sure though.

Comment: Ok, now see this is interesting .. by does the GCD need to be 1?

Comment: And yeah why the odd number comment?

Answer (score 1):

There are three possibilities:

1) The original author just constructed the hashing functions more or less randomly, saw that they worked well enough, and left it at that.

2) The original author had test data that well represented the actual data and saw that these functions worked extremely well for his exact application.

3) This code is performing very poorly and his hash table is not operating efficiently at all.

The only real requirement is that the output look evenly distributed over the hash table for whatever input he actually encounters and always produce the same output for the same input. While these kinds of functions generally perform poorly, they may be good enough for this specific application.

By the way, this type of open hashing doesn't work in the face of deletions. For example, say you add one record to the table. Then you go to add a second, but it collides with the first, so you skip forward to add the second. Everything's fine now -- you can find both the first record (directly) and the second record (by skipping over the first when you find it at the second record's hash location).

But if you delete the first record, how do you find the second? When you look at the second record's hash location, you find nothing. Do you try skipping? If so, how many times?

There are workarounds to these problems, but they tend to be very easy to do incorrectly.

Comment: This code is performing near optimally. I'm just perplexed by a 9 being multiplied with. I'm porting this code over, and someone asked me a in code review why 9 was there, I had no answer.

Comment: You should give us more context. What kind of things are being hashed?

Comment: This is basically two values, a 128-bit unsigned integer (exbPtr), and then a 16-bit integer (lgID) .. exbPtr is essentially a Guid, lgID generally tends to be smaller numbers.

Comment: @user986697: You can't know for sure why 9 was chosen initially, since you didn't choose it. But if it in fact evenly distributes the input data over the valid output space, then it is doing its job for this particular data set. You can test its performance by comparing the collision rate to the theoretically optimum collision rate (computed by assuming the output is random) and see. If the number of inputs is small compared to the hash space, being fast to compute may be more important.